# Improving performance of CSS3 animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, query-performance

My website runs amazing on FireFox but very scrappy on Chrome.
It is a full animated website with a lot of CSS3 scroll animations that are triggered with jQuery waypoints and a script i have written that adds and removes class with scroll.

Is there a way to force it perform much better on Chrome browser?

This is the website:
http://www.aikoncreative.com/

Comment: you're checking for two points with every animation. After the animation is complete you could just leave it instead of when scrolling up it goes back to its original state.

Comment: You do this [here](http://www.aikoncreative.com/en/web-development)

Comment: Yes, I'm repeating the animations on home page, inner pages the animations trigger only once. 

Triggering them once will no doubt improve the performance but will hurt the UX I'm trying to deliver.

I'm looking a solution that will allow me use the same animations as now but not scrapping.

Comment: How about a compromise - reset scroll-down the animation when it isn't currently in view and the viewport is above it. I only noticed the reverse animation when closely observing the site. Usually, when *I* browse (note: opinion), I will scroll down slowly but scroll back to the top quickly. Your reverse animation is only *really* visible at the bottom of my screen at the moment.

Comment: a plus is I'm not seeing negative performance except on the home page. There is a lot at play here. You got a huge video and a lot of animations (I say video, but maybe gif.. Idk didn't really look), but all of the loads come into play and then after a while they are mostly smooth. There are some loses just with the resets, but that is all I am seeing off.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated. You are using jQuery animations and there are some troubles with this:

1. jQuery.animate has a poor performance vs css animations, because not use the gpu, only the cpu, so movement is not so smooth as css transitions.
2. jQuery.animate not use requestAnimationFrame to perform animations. It use setTimeout or setInterval, so the performance is worst.

My recomendation is try to avoid jQuery animate function, create css classes to create native css animations and add class while are you scrolling AND (very important), optimize your scroll event using requestAnimationFrame and doing less calcs as possible.

Please, read this post from Paul Lewis, is very awesome: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/

**(edit) Add more info:**
 I deep inside your code a couple of minuts using chrome dev tools and I saw a terrible bottleneck on file SmoothScroll.js on function step called as: ssc_wheel => ssc_scroll => function step (33 seconds, 63 seconds ...). This function "step" takes a lot of execution time again and again, so cpu will killed. To enhace the performace, I recommend first call it using requestAnimationFrame and then we could see again if there is some positive effect (If you do well, you will see a better enhacement). Read the article to enhace scrolling with requestAnimationFrame :)

Keep this in mind while you will edit your code: "On events like scroll, put a boolean variable indicating that there is a event scroll, this variable set to true if it's value is false and then call your function to check or update animations using requestAnimationFrame like 'requestAnimationFrame(animateMyPage)'. In your function 'animateMyPage' check scroll position and add class to your animation objects, but be carefull, do as less operations as possible, if you have a lot of work to do in a frame you will need to wait next frame! At the end of 'animateMyPage' set to false variable used in scroll event too, to avoid unnecesary calls to requestAnimationFrame('animateMyPage').

These are some steps but there are much more, but, try to do this enhacements first.

Comment: Based on his question's wording, it sounds like he's using jQuery to trigger CSS3 animations, not to actually render them. Looking through some of the site's source code, there's plenty of places where `.css('animate: ....');` is called, rather than `fadeIn` etc. Also, CSS3 animations are only smoother *in principle*, some browsers have dog-slow implementations of CSS animations at the moment (although, generally speaking, you're right).

Comment: To add to this answer, you can also try using this library: https://github.com/gnarf/jquery-requestAnimationFrame which will switch `setTimeout` to `requestAnimationFrame` for jQuery. CSS animations present their own issues as well (most notably, you'll run into issues with auto-height and auto-width items).

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jose, I'm using jQuery only to trigger a class to the markup and the animation is performing in CSS3.

Comment: hi @user3586610 I deep inside your code a couple of minuts using chrome dev tools and i saw a terrible bottleneck on file SmoothScroll.js on function step called as: ssc_wheel => ssc_scroll => function step (33 seconds, 63 seconds ...). This function takes a lot of execution time during again and again, so cpu will killed. To enhace the performace, I recommend first call it using requestAnimationFrame and then we could see again if there is some positive effect (If you do well, you will see a better enhacement). Read the article to enhace scrolling with requestAnimationFrame :)

Comment: Oh thank you very much Jose, this is definitely something to work with!

Comment: You are welcome @user3586610 I will edit the post to add this info.